# The artifactory trusty repository is corrupt

Tags: artifactory, bintray

The checksums in the `Packages.bz2` file in jfrog's trusty repository for artifactory don't match the packages. This causes mirroring and installations to fail. Checked 19-Jul-2018 0606 UTC

```
$ curl -s https://jfrog.bintray.com/artifactory- 
debs/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages.bz2|bzcat|grep -A2 -F jfrog-artifactory-oss-6.1.0.deb
Filename: pool/main/j/jfrog-artifactory-oss-deb/jfrog-artifactory-oss-6.1.0.deb
SHA1: dfe6d0cce9c3ca946d27b8dd1cf080e0ef6b9818
SHA256: c88e6f2f183426721ce3273642e0df00abce2150c7ca67afe1a69b175e9775f6

$ curl -s https://jfrog.bintray.com/artifactory-debs/pool/main/j/jfrog-artifactory-oss-deb/jfrog-artifactory-oss-6.1.0.deb | sha1sum
da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709  -
$ curl -s https://jfrog.bintray.com/artifactory-debs/pool/main/j/jfrog-artifactory-oss-deb/jfrog-artifactory-oss-6.1.0.deb | sha256sum
e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855  -
```

Edit:

As has been kindly pointed out by Royg, I was missing the `-L` flag to `curl` in order to follow bintray's redirects. However, that then exposes an issue with the package for version 4.3.1:

```
$ curl -sL https://jfrog.bintray.com/artifactory-debs/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages.bz2 | bzcat | grep -A2 -F jfrog-artifactory-oss-4.3.1.deb
Filename: pool/main/j/jfrog-artifactory-oss-deb/jfrog-artifactory-oss-4.3.1.deb
SHA1: dc8b12436f309b538f6b80b4027b797e3cfce897
SHA256: 8cad6699ff17866b93a02124254ba3fb9a3ca2036048161b9bd3a49c8257831f

$ curl -sL https://jfrog.bintray.com/artifactory-debs/pool/main/j/jfrog-artifactory-oss-deb/jfrog-artifactory-oss-4.3.1.deb | sha1sum
575dc3debd016ff3a21e635625de266a6b0c2e48  -
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the redirect option in your curl `-L` or `--location`.

If you try the `curl` command to the artifact with `-v` or `--verbose` you can seen that Bintray is redirecting you to the CDN nearest you. That means that you are `sha1sum` and `sha256sum` on empty artifact, that is why the checksum doesn't match.

`$ curl https://jfrog.bintray.com/artifactory-debs/pool/main/j/jfrog-artifactory-oss-deb/jfrog-artifactory-oss-6.1.0.deb -vL | sha1sum
dfe6d0cce9c3ca946d27b8dd1cf080e0ef6b9818  -
$ curl https://jfrog.bintray.com/artifactory-debs/pool/main/j/jfrog-artifactory-oss-deb/jfrog-artifactory-oss-6.1.0.deb -vL | sha256sum
c88e6f2f183426721ce3273642e0df00abce2150c7ca67afe1a69b175e9775f6  -`

Comment: OK well thanks for pointing out my glaring error.. now the plot thickens.. the thing which initially triggered this 'discovery' was a failure when mirroring the repo using aptly

`ERROR: unable to update: download errors:
  https://jfrog.bintray.com/artifactory-debs/pool/main/j/jfrog-artifactory-oss-deb/jfrog-artifactory-oss-4.3.1.deb: sha1 hash mismatch "575dc3debd016ff3a21e635625de266a6b0c2e48" != "dc8b12436f309b538f6b80b4027b797e3cfce897"
`

I'll do some more digging

Comment: It looks like only `jfrog-artifactory-oss-4.3.1.deb` has this issue, checksum matches on 4.3.0 and 4.3.2, you can contact Bintray's support.